# Issues in displaying a Welcome Message using Labels in Production Environment

Tags: asp.net, session-variables

I want to display a simple welcome message in the body using a Label in ASP.Net web page.

The scenario is, when a user successfully logs in, a Welcome Message "Welcome FirstName" is displayed on the web page using Sessions.

I have developed it in dev environment is working fine but when I deployed it in remote production server it's not being displayed. And as a matter of fact, within the same application in production, sessions are configured properly when the user logs in. Some links are enabled and disabled properly according to the sessions configuration. Even the FullName of the logged in user in Production is displayed in the header of the Master Page. The issue is only with this message in the body and only in Production Environment. Its not getting displayed but the page opens without any errors except that the Welcome Message is ignored completely. I have verified the Session Name syntax etc, i couldnt find any compilation errors etc

Below is the piece of code of my implementation:

code in .aspx extension:

```
<center>
                  <h2><b>Welcome to Baraamej Website</b></h2>
                  <p>This is a private website</p>
                   <asp:Label Style="color: green" Font-Bold="true" ID="Lbl_HelloMsg" Font-Size="XX-Large" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
               </center>
```

code behind:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // display Welcome User Message
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                // display Hello User Message
                //Lbl_HelloMsg.Text += "Welcome " + (String)Session["FullName"];
                Lbl_HellowMsg.Text = "Hellos " + Session["FullName"].ToString(); // display hello user string
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the !IsPostBack.

In 99% of cases, YES you do want that test/check and code stub of !IsPostBack.

However, in this case you don't want that test/check. Any navigation to a new page will trigger master load first, then child page load event. And any button click in child form will in general cause a re-load of the master page content, and thus the label value will not been seen.

Try removing the !IsPostBack check, and just set the label each time based on session.

Comment: Hi Albert, I have removed the IsPostBack but the behavior is still the same. The Welcome Message is not getting displayed. In Dev, it still works fine even without IsPostBack

Comment: don't see why dev vs production would make a difference, unless session() is working different here (if you using AWS or some type of clustered web hosting, then you have to use sql based sessions, since the server "memory" for session can't be shared between the multiple (possible) copies of a web server being used. This would suggest that session is not working correctly on production. You don't mention if you turned on sql based sessions, and you don't mention the type of hosted server you are using compared to your dev box.